# Combining div and span tag styles failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are two types of help text container I have. One is in `<div>` other is in `<span>`
I wrote a css both in one style. It's working good but those `<div>` and `<spans>` includes an arrow styled **child** `<div>` and `<span>`. I tried to combine that `.arrow` styles but it failed in practice. Is there a way combine those same styles?

HTML example for `<div>`:

```
<div class="helptext" id="{{ id_for_label }}">
    <div class="arrow"></div> Helptext is in here
</div>
```

HTML example for `<span>`:

```
<span class="helptext" id="{{ id_for_label }}">
    <span class="arrow"></span> Helptext is in here
</span>
```

CSS for both:

```
div[class="helptext"],span[class="helptext"] {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3c578c;
    background-color: #FCFCF0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 1px dimgray;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index:100000;
}
```

CSS .arrow example for `<div>`:

```
div[class="helptext"] .arrow {display: block; position: absolute; border: 10px solid transparent;
                                  border-bottom-color: #3c578c; top: -20px; right: 10px;}
```

CSS .arrow example for `<span>`:

```
span[class="helptext"] .arrow {display: block; position: absolute; border: 10px solid transparent;
                                   border-bottom-color: #3c578c; top: -20px; right: 10px;}
```

I can't combine last two css.

Comment: the correct notation is `span.helptext {}`, or even just `.helptext {}`. and therefore, the syntax you would use would be `.helptext .arrow {}`.

Comment: Just use .helptext .arrow if you want to to apply to any element. You could use div.helptext .arrow, span.helptext .arrow if you want to constrain to DIV/SPAN's

Comment: span is designed to contain text, it's kind of the last element before text.
div is designed to contain other elements like p or span.
Ideally span should not contain span and text should not be alone in a div with another div.

Comment: This is a large project and I don't want to write imprecise styles. That's why I want to use exact selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.arrow` in both selectors for your css

Use this

```
div[class="helptext"] .arrow,span[class="helptext"] .arrow{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3c578c;
    background-color: #FCFCF0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 1px dimgray;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index:100000;
}
```

I think you can `.helptext .arrow` as selector, if you don't have another element with classname `helptext`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code:

```
.helptext {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3c578c;
    background-color: #FCFCF0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 1px dimgray;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index:100000;
}
.helptext .arrow { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #3c578c; 
    top: -20px; 
    right: 10px;
}
```